# Problems with connecting Raspberry Pi successfully to M100 through serial port

Tags: dji-sdk

Currently I am trying to mount a raspberry pi 3 as my onboard device onto my M100. I am connecting my pi by connecting the UART_CAN2 port to the GND, TXD, and RXD pins of my pi with the provided UART serial cable. I am using the 3.1 branch of the SDK provided by DJI on Github, which is compatible with the M100. When I try to execute djiosdk-linux-sample from my build directory, this comes up:

```
User Configuration read successfully. 

These are your User_Config settings.
Serial port = /dev/ttyS0
Baudrate = 115200
Drone/FC Version: M100
SDK Version: 3.1
App ID: MY_APP_ID_XXXXXXX
App Key: MY_APP_KEY_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Does everything look correct? If not, navigate to Linux/UserConfig.txt and make changes.

STATUS init,line 51: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyS0 with baudrate 115200...
STATUS init,line 60: ...Serial started successfully.

Attempting activation..
Automatic activation successful.
Failed to obtain control.
Your RC mode switch is not in mode F. (Is the RC connected and paired?)
This program will exit now.
```

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but I haven't found any compelling answers. My remote is on mode F, and it is recognized as so on the Assistant application. However, I know that is not the problem. I have heard from other people online (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/issues/77), that the remote controller and its mode is not the core of the problem. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Any help would be great.

Thanks,
AWATHIEU

Comment: Did you eventually solve this?